# Docker for Windows, Alpine container + JRE, Insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue

Tags: java, docker

I am trying to run a Java application inside an Alpine-based Docker container on Docker for Windows and am getting, "There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue."

`free -m` inside the container shows my container has only 962MB total memory and 0 swap.

My Docker installation is using Hyper-V, and the Moby Linux VM has 4GB of memory allotted to it. I'm also using the `-m 2g` flag on my `docker run` command to set a limit higher than 1GB. This isn't working. I still get 962/0 whether I use the -m command or not, and I can't find any way to get swap.

The only information I can find on memory limiting is to use the `-m` flag. But I don't understand why it's not doing anything when running a Linux container on Docker for Windows?

Comment: Silly questions: Q: You're using a 64-bit JRE in your container, correct?  Q: What happens with `docker run -m 2GB ...` ("GB" vs. "g")?  Q: Could you show us your complete "run" command?

Comment: Yes, 64-bit Java. The command `docker run -m 2GB` doesn't work, as valid units for this `-m` flag in Docker are `k`, `m`, `g`, etc. The full Docker command is: `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh --rm -m 2g <image>`

Comment: For whatever it's worth, some documentation says `-m 2GB`, other documentation says `-m=2g` ... and I honestly don't know which are or aren't valid for your scenario :(  ALSO: You should be able to query the container's upper limit here: `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes`.  Q: What's configured for the "whale" icon on your Windows GUI (I only have Docker on Ubuntu Linux, at the moment...)